# Specific search terms return 500

Tags: content-search, solr

We are on `Sitecore 9.0.1` and `Solr version 6.6.2` and have previously had issues with populating our schemas from the `Sitecore control panel`. After overriding the pipeline like in this blog post (https://mikael.com/2018/01/working-with-content-search-and-solr-in-sitecore-9/) all our indexes build.

However, we are still seeing issues for some specific search terms for the Norwegian language in our later environments. I can not reproduce the issue locally despite having identical databases, schema files, code and search config.

Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: Hi @sitecore_emil, Is there any error log generated? If yes, you can add it to the question.